# Php contact form errors

Tags: php, contact-form

I'm building a php contact form that checks if some fields are filled it or not (no ajax). 
The form is not working for 100%. I will try to explain. When I submit my form, The user navigates to http://mydomain.com/send.php 
There is receive my error messages (if there are any). When I refresh the send.php page I receive the following errors: **Notice: Undefined index: name in /Library/WebServer/Documents/~aledvertising/send.php**

Here is my code

**html form**

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
    <div id="form-top">

    </div>
    <div id="form-left">  
<label>Naam:<span class="star">*</span></label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Uw naam">


    <label>Email:<span class="star">*</span></label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Uw email">

    <label>Hoeveel is 2+2? (Anti-spam)<span class="star">*</span></label>
<input name="human" placeholder="Uw antwoord">

    </div>
    <div id="form-right">
    <label>Uw bericht:<span class="star">*</span></label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Uw bericht"></textarea>
    </div>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Verzenden">
</form>
```

**SEND.PHP**

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: ' . $_POST['email']; 
    $to  = 'myemail@mail.com' . ', '; 
    $to .= $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'Uw vraag op www.aledvertising.be';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\nMessage:\n $message";
 ?>
 <?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $message != '') {
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p class="green">Uw bericht is succesvol verzonden.</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Er iets misgelopen, probeer opnieuw aub.</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>2+2 is niet gelijk aan het getal dat u hebt ingevoerd.</p>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<p>Alle velden met een * zijn verplicht in te vullen.</p>';
    }
}
    ?>
```

Can somebody please help me to get a full working form? Thank you

Comment: Read up on http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Mail header injection is possible with your form. **Never** trust those `$_POST` variables. And aren't you supposed to celebrate Queen's Day today? ;-)

Comment: Looks like it's not set and just giving you a notice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) method from php.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{
//code here

}
?>
```

The problem is that when you reload the page, the server side code looks for the index `name` and it does not find it because `name` does not have any value yet. The value is received once you submit the page. So that's why the error is there.

**update**

The error is that when you submit the form, there are some fields that may be send empty, so once that the post values goes to send.php there are $_POST that will be expecting values. if some of them do not recive does values, it will tell you: "Hey, i do not have values, so i im null". That why you have to check that the fields are all filled or make a validation on server side.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"],$_POST["last_name"],etc,etc))
{
//if everything ok, ill go on.
}
else{
//if there are empty field, go back
}

?>
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
if (isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['message'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: ' . $_POST['email']; 
    $to  = 'myemail@mail.com' . ', '; 
    $to .= $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'Uw vraag op www.aledvertising.be';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\nMessage:\n $message";
    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $message != '') {
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p class="green">Uw bericht is succesvol verzonden.</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Er iets misgelopen, probeer opnieuw aub.</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>2+2 is niet gelijk aan het getal dat u hebt ingevoerd.</p>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<p>Alle velden met een * zijn verplicht in te vullen.</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks EinerS, but the action (send.php) is correct on the html form page? I just have to edit my send.php ?

Comment: Could be Yes or not. Why? Well whenever if send.php is in the same directory, yes. If not, no. See [see here ](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm) for more information about relative and absolute path please.

Comment: EinerS, I understand the relative, absolute path. Send.php is in the same directory. Just to be sure what I have to do:

Comment: Your link is broken. Use `[this form](http://example.com)` to create a hyperlink.

Comment: Sorry for that. Done. You can check now.

Comment: From this line if ($_POST['submit']) { ... I have to use the isset function?

Comment: @NielsJansen: It goes wrong already at the first line. You should check *all* `$_POST` variables. Does the form send an email the first time you submit it?

Comment: Yes the form is working well, It just crashes when I refresh the send.php

Comment: @NielsJansen: And it doesn't ask you to resubmit the form? If so, if you press 'cancel', no variables will be sent so `$_POST['name']` is just not set.

Comment: I understand what an isset function does (checks if a variable is not null) but I'm a little bit lost here. I really don't know what I have to change to receive NO errors.

Comment: @NielsJansen validate if all $_POST are not empty and it will work.

Comment: @NielsJansen post are saved in cache, which mean that once you reload the page, the value send again. that why the alert message. Marcel Korpel is right, if cancel is pressed, no variable will be send.

Comment: EinerS see the post of digitizer below. Is that the correct way?

Comment: Also check the presence of `$_POST['human']` and `$_POST['submit']` before using them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: ' . $_POST['email']; 
    $to  = 'myemail@mail.com' . ', '; 
    $to .= $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'Uw vraag op www.aledvertising.be';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\nMessage:\n $message";
    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $message != '') {
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p class="green">Uw bericht is succesvol verzonden.</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Er iets misgelopen, probeer opnieuw aub.</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>2+2 is niet gelijk aan het getal dat u hebt ingevoerd.</p>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<p>Alle velden met een * zijn verplicht in te vullen.</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

setting the isset() function and then declaring the variables worked for me, tested it in my server, not giving any errors and form is submitted successfully...

please check it once...

Comment: This is working for me! Thanks digitiZer! BUT one question, is this the correct way of dealing with the forms.?

Comment: @NielsJansen: No, you cannot assume that because `$_POST['submit']` is present, all the other ones are also present.

Comment: I really don't understand it anymore. I receive no errors with the code from digitizer but I never receive an email anymore. I just don't know how to change my code. I don't know what to write after if(isset($_POST["name"],$_POST["last_name"],etc,etc))

Comment: the email you saying, is it the value of email form field or actual email not sent? also i have seen that email value you are using is myemail@mail.com.??

Comment: Thank you EinerS. The form is working for 100% now. Is this also 100% save. (read something about header injection). Question 2: The email I receive is plain text without any layout, can I adjust this?

Comment: @NielsJansen: No, it's still not safe, you should check whether `$_POST['email']` contains a valid email address, otherwise it's easy to inject `\r\nBcc: spamaddresses@example.com` in your form.

Comment: @NielsJansen if it worked, mark my answer as the select one for other who have the same problem see at once what is happening them.

Comment: @EinerS according to first line in your solution, the line `if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $message != '') {` from OP becomes unnecessary....

Comment: @digitiZer did you know that when you press the space bar, that counts as a value? Try this code <html><input type="text" onkeyup="value(this)"> <script>function value(object){alert(object.value.length);} </script></html> and press the space bar and see by yourself why "" its not safe :D

Comment: @digitiZer: No, that's not true: there's a difference between a variable being set and a variable being empty.